# Can i link from pictures' parts?

Tags: html, css

i want to link background image's parts. i must put middle of screen. so, image property;

background: 'bg.png'
background-size: contain;

Can i link from pictures' parts?

http://cl.ly/image/1R2M1E2o0R0F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wont be able to add clickable areas to a background image, so there are two approaches you could take.

1. Image map
   This lets you use the `<img` tag and map areas to be 'clickable', i.e.

`<img src='' usemap='#myMap />`

```
<map name="myMap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,50,50" href="somewhere.html">
</map>
```

You can use online generators to do it for you such as [Image map tool](http://www.image-maps.com/)

2. Position elements over the top

Another option, is to have an background image on the parent element, and have positioned, 'clickable' element inside it, such as

```
#parent{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-image:url();
    position:relative;
}

#someLink{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    position:absolute;
    left:20px;
    top:50px;
}
```

You'd use the absolutely positioned element as your 'clickable' areas and position them over the background image.

If you background is inside a responsive element/layout, they you can use percentages to ensure the clickable areas respond too.

Comment: can you show example for responsive image? i can't it, sorry

Comment: here is a [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/odfd1rn4/) to show responsive positioning